# nightwatch: distribute test with specific firefox profile

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, profile, nightwatch.js

Here is my problem: I want be abble to set firefox in specific language to run our e2e tests, and be abble to distribute them.

all verions:

Mozilla Firefox 53.0.3

Selenium 3.4.0 (from npm)

geckodriver 0.17.0 (from npm)

nightwatch.conf.js:

```
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');

module.exports = {
    "src_folders": [
        "test/functional/features"
    ],
    "custom_commands_path": [
        "test/functional/commands/commun",
        "test/functional/commands/project"
    ],
    "output_folder": false,
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": seleniumServer.path,
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./node_modules/.bin/geckodriver"
        }
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "detailed_output": false,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "marionette": true,
                "browserName": "firefox"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In general I tryed two way:

- dynamically create a firefox profile, and use it.

In theorie, I can use a before(Each) and use `firefox-profile`. In practice it create my profile but doesn't use it.

```
const FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

function setProfile(browser, profile, callback) {
    profile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        browser.options.desiredCapabilities['firefox_profile'] = encodedProfile;
        callback();
    });
}

function setPrefToFrench(browser, done) {
    var FFprofile = new FirefoxProfile();

    FFprofile.setPreference('general.useragent.locale', 'fr');
    FFprofile.setPreference('intl.accept_languages', 'fr');

    setProfile(browser, FFprofile, done);
}

module.exports = {
    'default' : {
        isLocal : true
    },

    beforeEach: function(browser, done) {
        setPrefToFrench(browser, done);
        done();
    }
};
```

- Save a profile (why not ziped) and include it in project

The same, in theorie, i just have to add it on the nightwatch.conf.js

```
"selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": seleniumServer.path,
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
        "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./node_modules/.bin/geckodriver",
        "webdriver.firefox.profile": "path/to/my/profile(or base64 zip)"
    }
},
```

But all time the same, my firefox is still in english.

Does anyone whould have a solution, or maybe I made something wrong?